# Trigger after delete more than 1 record

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

There is a problem when I delete all records.

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER update_StuIns_OnDelete 
ON Class
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Instructor_ID TABLE (id BIGINT);

    INSERT INTO @Instructor_ID 
        SELECT prevC.c_InstructorID 
        FROM deleted prevC

    DECLARE @Institute_ID TABLE (id BIGINT);

    INSERT INTO @Institute_ID 
        SELECT prevC.c_InstituteID 
        FROM deleted prevC

    DECLARE @Instrument_ID TABLE (id BIGINT);

    INSERT INTO @Instrument_ID 
        SELECT prevC.c_InstrumentID 
        FROM deleted prevC

    DECLARE @Student_Id TABLE (id BIGINT);

    INSERT INTO @Student_Id 
        SELECT prevC.c_StudentID 
        FROM deleted prevC

    IF ((SELECT Learning_Time FROM Is_Learning
         WHERE l_StudentID IN (SELECT id FROM @Student_Id) 
           AND l_InstrumentID IN (SELECT id FROM @Instrument_ID)) IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        DELETE Is_Learning
        WHERE l_StudentID IN (SELECT id FROM @Student_Id) 
            AND l_InstrumentID IN (SELECT id FROM @Instrument_ID)
    END

    IF((SELECT Teaching_Time FROM Teaches
        WHERE t_InstructorID IN (SELECT id FROM @Instructor_ID)
          AND t_InstrumentID IN (SELECT id FROM @Instrument_ID)) IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        DELETE Teaches
        WHERE t_InstructorID IN (SELECT id FROM @Instructor_ID)
            AND t_InstrumentID IN (SELECT id FROM @Instrument_ID)
    END

    IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Class C 
                  WHERE C.c_InstructorID IN (SELECT id FROM @Instructor_ID) 
                    AND C.c_InstituteID IN (SELECT id FROM @Institute_ID)))
    BEGIN
        DELETE Is_MemberOf
        WHERE m_InstructorID IN (SELECT id FROM @Instructor_ID)
            AND m_InstituteID IN (SELECT id FROM @Institute_ID)
    END
END;
```

When I want to delete 1 row, it works correctly, but for multiple rows, I get this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure update_StuIns_OnDelete, Line 13
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Any suggestion for this problem?

Comment: Triggers are (like everything in a database) set based, this means that `deleted` and `inserted` are tables. When you delete more than one row, then the `deleted`  table will hold more than one row, hence you cannot ever assign that to a single variable

Comment: You should write your delete statement in your trigger with a join to the `deleted` table, that way you have no longer this problem, and you don't need any of your variables anymore

Comment: Your `IF` statements assum that the queries will only return 1 row.

Comment: Probably worth reading [this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: Best practice is to list the columns being inserted into.

Comment: Stop blindly applying the pattern of storing intermediate (and trivial) resultsets in temp tables or table vars.

Comment: Sorry
I'm new in this industry.
I'm trying to get better in optimized query.

Answer (score 2):

You have three `if` statements in your logic. `if ((select ... is null)`, another `if ((select ... is null`, and an `if (not exists ...)`

In the first two cases, you are comparing the result of a `select` statement (which returns a set of rows) against `null`. But null is a single scalar. You can't compare a whole column against `null`.

Change those two to match the `not exists` construction of the third `if`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked correctly.

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER update_StuIns_OnDelete ON Class
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT Learning_Time FROM Is_Learning INNER JOIN
        deleted d ON l_StudentID = d.c_StudentID AND l_InstrumentID = d.c_InstrumentID 
        WHERE Learning_Time IS NULL))
    BEGIN
        DELETE Is_Learning
        FROM Is_Learning INNER JOIN
        deleted d ON l_StudentID = d.c_StudentID AND l_InstrumentID = d.c_InstrumentID 
    END
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT Teaching_Time FROM Teaches INNER JOIN
        deleted d ON t_InstructorID = d.c_InstructorID AND t_InstrumentID = d.c_InstrumentID 
        WHERE Teaching_Time IS NULL))
    BEGIN
        DELETE Teaches
        FROM Teaches INNER JOIN
        deleted d ON t_InstructorID = d.c_InstructorID AND t_InstrumentID = d.c_InstrumentID 
    END
    IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Class C INNER JOIN deleted d
    ON C.c_InstructorID = d.c_InstructorID AND C.c_InstituteID = d.c_InstituteID))
    BEGIN
        DELETE Is_MemberOf
        FROM Is_MemberOf INNER JOIN
        deleted d ON m_InstructorID = d.c_InstructorID AND m_InstituteID = d.c_InstituteID 
    END
END;
```

Comment: You don't need the IF statements to check for existence before deleting.  The delete and the join will only delete the rows if they exist - so checking to see if they exist is redundant.  You also should review CASCADE which would solve this for you by cascading the delete through the related tables.